# MKMapView Funny Buissness

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mkmapview

im trying to create a show on map section in my app, but for some reason the annotations will not place correctly

```
    MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView*)self.view;

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

coordinate.latitude = 55.065767;

coordinate.longitude = -2.724609;



mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 500000, 500000);
mapView.delegate = self;


for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {

    coordinate.latitude = latitude;
    coordinate.longitude = longitude;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = {coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude};
    PlaceAnnotation* annotation = [[PlaceAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord];
    //annotation.mTitle = companyTitle;
    //annotation.mSubtitle = companyDescription;
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    [annotation release];

}


}
```

and in my place annotaion

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

self = [super init];

if (self != nil) {

    _coordinate = coordinate;



}

return self;

}
```

lattitude and longditude both have the right values, i have used this code before but using an array pointing to an object and it works fine , but when i try to give it the values directly it fails

can anyone help me out

*edit , sorry i already have my Viewforannotation just got missed out in the copy

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
if(annotation != mV.userLocation) 
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
    pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mV dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
        pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;




    //instatiate a detail-disclosure button and set it to appear on right side of annotation

}

return pinAnnotation;
[pinAnnotation release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PlaceAnnotation needs to implement the MKAnnotation protocol. Specifically, the method

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate)coordinate;
```

or you can define the property and set it in your constructor

```
@property (assign) CLLocationCoordinate coordinate
```

This is how the MKMapView knows where to place the annotation.

p.s.
Also, I'm not sure how kosher this is:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = {coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude};
```

It's probably fine, but Apple recommend:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

to supply an MKAnnotationView instance (or subclass) to use to display the annotation. Go see the [MKMapViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) for details.